# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngforOf'

Tags: angular, ngfor

Guys I know theres plenty of info about the specific error, but I literally did what they suggest and Im still missing something.
So I have an array inside my component.ts and Im trying to display it via *ngfor inside my component.html..
so Im getting that error said in the title, but I tried to create a simple array of string and loop through it and it actually worked.
in the following photos ull be able to see the commented array I was able to loop through in both .ts and .html and the one that didnt work (member: Member[]) also in both, thanks in advance!!

edit: comp.html shows 'let member of member' but its actually of **members**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWW4n.jpg

Comment: Please, don't post images of your code, instead, paste it directly and format it like code.

Answer (score 0):

Add BrowserModule to imports in NgModule if it's the root module (AppModule), otherwise the CommonModule.

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser'

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule],
})
```

Comment: thats actually what Im doing. I tried importing both browsermodule and commonmodule ( in two different tries ) and still doesnt seem to be working..

Comment: in which module do you declare MemberListComponent?